# Why does $dy=a\cos\theta d\theta$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve a line integral where $C$ is the circle $|z|=a$ oriented clockwise. I know that I have to convert $f(x,\,y)$ to $f(r,\,\theta)$. However, I do not understand why $dy=a\cos\theta d\theta$. I'm aware the $y=a\sin\theta$, and the derivative of this is where $a\cos\theta d\theta$ comes from. But I am unsure why and how. Perhaps,

This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: $
dy = \frac{{dy}}{{d\theta }}d\theta  = \frac{{d(a\sin \theta )}}{{d\theta }}d\theta  = (a\cos \theta) d\theta 
$

Comment: Yes, we have a function $y=a \cos \theta$; when we derive it the parameter $a$ is constant and we derive the function $\cos \theta$ which is a function of variable $\theta$. See [Derivative of trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions#Derivative_of_the_sine_function).

Comment: The usual parameterization of $r=a$ is $x=a\cos\theta,\,y=a\sin\theta$.

Answer (score -1):

For a circle radius $a$

$$x=a \cos \theta , y= a \sin \theta $$

Differentiate $ y= a \sin \theta... $   w.r.t. $\theta $

$$ dy =a \cos \theta d\theta $$